# How to connect from outside to MongoDB Atlas under VPC peering?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I have:

1. MongoDB Atlas Cluster
2. VPC Peering between GCP.

When I tried connect to DB from my home laptop:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://hello-dev-x53pa.gcp.mongodb.net/test" --username myuser
```

I received an error:

```
2020-01-09T15:32:33.697+0200 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Failed to connect to 192.168.240.4:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2020-01-09T15:32:33.698+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 192.168.240.2:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
```

I see that received local IP address but I don't understand how I can connect to the my DB which in the private VPC?

I will be very happy for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to whitelist your IP address. VPC Peering allowed GCP resources to connect to your database, but you also need to specify your private IP address.

Refer to below document to add IP address:

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/#add-whitelist-entries

**EDIT:**
I wouldn't whitelist all IP addresses, just use the "current IP address" option to white list the IP address your laptop is trying to access from.

Also, try adding `--password` option, as this should be used in conjunction with `--username` option. Also, confirm that "test" db is where you created the username/password.

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://hello-dev-x53pa.gcp.mongodb.net/test" --username myuser --password mypassword
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I have private IP address. BTW in the white list added 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I made edits to reflect your comment. Please let me know if this helps. If the updated answer didn't help, I will remove it.

Comment: I have tried this solution as well, but it does not work. My hypothesis is that the IP addresses that we add to the whitelist for a project which has VPC Peering enabled are only for those internal to that network. In fact, when creating the VPC Peering for a project in Atlas, it says "Enabling VPC Peering on GCP means: Connections from public IPs outside of the peered VPC will not be able to reach dedicated MongoDB Atlas clusters."